# how to create star icon in each row angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to make star icon in each row.I am generating the row dynamically but I am able to generate rows but my star icon is visible on upper of top row why ..I need to show start icon in each row .
http://plnkr.co/edit/mBoAX5xaVTYvdrRuafEw?p=preview

```
<table ng-table class="table">
    <tr ng-repeat="guitar in guitarVariable" style="border: 5px solid #000000; background: pink" >
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> 

        <td data-title="'Name'">{{guitar.color}} </td>


        <td data-title="'class'">{{guitar.value}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>` inside of td

http://plnkr.co/edit/APJ7mvfFrDNSWF2pKQ6m?p=preview

Comment: thanks for giving a nice answer ..last can we show some pop up on each star icon

Comment: mean it popover should be same ..but it show on star button click..how er can show that

Comment: i think i need make a derctive ?

Comment: you can use third party directives as well

Comment: i already study that but i am not able to show on each star icon

Comment: i just want want a simple popover on each icon using directive or other method

Comment: but where is plunker pls give url

Comment: But there is not popover in that pluner.please check there is no tooltio and popover

Comment: I can see popover on each star on mouseenter

Comment: please give plunker link

Comment: have you press save button .increase the version of plunker

Comment: please increase the version of plunker

Comment: please paste your code on answer so that i will understant